# android error: IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation

Tags: android

I have an activity that open from browser when Device is in Landscape get me below error

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation**

**Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".Activity.MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Theme_Slide"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="xxx"
                android:scheme="xxx" />
            <data
                android:host="xxx"
                android:scheme="xxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Theme_Slide" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE FIND SOLUTION**

In android Oreo (API 26) you can not change orientation for Activity that have below line in style

```
 <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

You have two way for solving this :

1. You can simply remove above line (or turn it to false) and your app works fine.
2. Or you can first remove below line from manifest for that activity

   android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Then you must add this line to java file

//android O fix bug orientation

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```